# Compiling a binary to work with valgrind on Snow Leopard

Tags: g++, osx-snow-leopard, valgrind

I installed valgrind on Snow Leopard using the patch at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205241 . However, when I run it with a binary I compiled from C++ code, I'm told that valgrind "cannot execute binary file". What g++ flags should I set to make my program work with valgrind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to use the -m32 option to generate a 32-bit executable.  The compiler default is 64-bit (assuming you have a 64-bit machine), but valgrind does not yet officially support 64-bit executables on Mac OS X.  The `file` command on your executable should report "Mach-O executable i386".

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. However, I couldn't get it to compile. I'm using a makefile to do all this, and after adding the -m32 option, I'm told that "file is not of required architecture" for all of my .o files.

Comment: You need -m32 for both compiling and linking; it sounds like you may have added it for compiling only.  Also be sure that you have 32-bit versions of all the libraries you are using.